# Python filter larger text by quantile

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, filter, quantile

Assume I am process a very large text file,
I have the following pseudocode

```
xx_valueList = []
lines=[]
with line in file: 
    xx_value = calc_xxValue(line)
    xx_valueList.append(xx_value)
    lines.append(lines)

# get_quantile_value is a function return the cutoff value with a specific quantile precent
cut_offvalue = get_quantile_value(xx_valueList, precent=0.05)
for line in lines: 
    if calc_xxValue(line) > cut_offvalue: 
         # do someting here
```

Note that the file is very large and may come from a pipe, so I don't want to read it twice.

We must read the entire file before we can get the cutoff to filter file

The above method can work, but it consumes too much memory, is there some algorithmic optimization that can improve efficiency and reduce memory consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xx_value_list = []
cut_offvalue = 0
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        xx_value = calc_xxValue(line)
        xx_value_list.append(xx_value)
        if len(xx_value_list) % 100 == 0:
            cut_offvalue = get_quantile_value(xx_value_list, precent=0.05)
        if xx_value < cut_offvalue: 
            # do something here
            pass
```

Comment: The problem is that the cut_offvalue here is determined based on all the rows and needs to be applied to all the rows. For example, we need to discard the rows whose xx_value is in the top five percent. However, before we read all the rows, We have no way of knowing what the cutoff is

Comment: one approach could be to use an iterative algorithm that processes the file one line at a time, keeping track of the xx_values and updating the cut-off value as needed. In this other version of the code, the file is read line by line, and the xx_value of each line is stored in the xx_value_list. After every 100 lines, the cut_offvalue is recalculated using the updated xx_value_list. Then the xx value of the current line is compared with the cut_offvalue, if it's less than cut_offvalue the line is processed.
I will update my reply above to show what I mean.

Comment: Ok, I got that,  I hope its will work well, thanks